# How to use JavaScript to style the code in a pre element?

Tags: javascript, html, pre

How is it possible to highlight the code inside a pre element? There is already questions about highlighting it, but the answers is all in JQuery. Is it possible to do it without the tags and it's id in JavaScript and not JQuery. I don't want the whole code block to be the same colour I want every tag-open and tag-close to be a colour, the tag value to be another colour and the attributes and it's value to be another colour.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("idofpre").style.color="#99999";
```

Comment: Have you not seen I said to not have the colour of the whole text block be the same and every item for himself. For example the tag open and tag close one colour and the attributes another colour. Please read again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
document.getElementById("the_id_of_pre_block").style.property="value";
```

The upper code will get the ID of the element and update the style. Second thing you can use TagName too:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("pre").style.property="value";
```

Or else you can use jQuery (the easier way but not your way) to style the content.  Using this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('pre').css('background-color', '#anyhexcode');
});
```

This will change the `background-color` of all the text placed inside the `pre` block. That's what you can do with JavaScript.

**One more thing:**

You are using `onload=hightlight()` but you are having a function as `colorize()` are you sure that's good? I think you need to change that!

Comment: Have you not seen I said to not have the colour of the whole text block be the same and every item for himself. For example the tag open and tag close one colour and the attributes another colour. Please read again.

Comment: Then you can use `document.getElementById()` and then use the id of different elements and change their style.

Comment: Please read again, I do not want the tags and their  id's to be in the pre, I only want the code to be there. Otherwise I'll have to add a tag and it's id to every part of the code in the code block.